# Mapping from a Single Source to A Nested Class(es)

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map data from a single class call it `MCI` which is used as the context class

```
public class MCI {
 public string sessionId {get; set;}
 [Key]
 public Guid Userid {get; set;}
 public string Username {get; set;}
 public string SocialServiceNo {get; set;}
 public string Employee_No {get; set;}
 public string Employer {get; set;}
 public string MCIBranch {get; set; }
}
```

The class am mapping to consists of fields

```
public class MCIDto{
 public string MCIBranch {get; set; }
 public UserDetails UserDetails {get; set;}
 public EmployementDetails EmpDetails {get; set;}
}
```

Here are my other classes;

```
public class UserDetails{
 public string sessionId {get; set;}
 public Guid Userid {get; set;}
 public string Username {get; set;}
 public string SocialServiceNo {get; set;}
```

}

```
public class EmploymentDetails {
  public string Employee_No {get; set;}
 public string Employer {get; set;}
```

}

I have structured my DTO in this way because am Serializing.
I would like to know how using Automapper I can map data from `MCI` to `MCIDetails`.

Comment: I think I see something here to try first https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [comment posted](https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/) I found a solution which was pretty straight forward.
I had to Initialize the Mapper and set the properties

```
 Mapper.Initialize(conf => {
  conf.CreateMap<MCI, MCIDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.UserDetails, m => m.MapFrom(src => new UserDetails {
      sessionId = src.sessionId,
      Userid = src.Userid,
      Username = src.Username,
      SocialServiceNo = src.SocialServiceNo
    }))
   .ForMember( dest => dest.EmpDetails, m => m.MapFrom(src => new EmployementDetails {
      Employee_No = src.Employee_No,
      Employer = src.Employer
   }))
 });
```